# Create PDF contains Image & send it to DropBox in my Android App

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I want to create an PDF that contains images. I have used the iText library to create the text portion of the PDF, but have been unable to find any way to add images.

Separately, I would also like to upload this to dropbox after creating the PDF.

Does anybody have any suggestions of where to look?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.

It is a c/c++ library and is required to use as JNI in android. You can use JMagick as wrapper for java

Comment: And what about to upload these PDF on Dropbox